# List sharepoint sites with communication or team site type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am working on microsoft-365. Is there any api(graph,sharepoint Rest etc.,) to list sites along with the type of site whether that is a communication or team site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a bit of CSOM which returns list of Site Info objects. An object has 'Template' property with site template.

- 'SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0' for Communication site
- 'GROUP#0' for Team site

```
    var context = this.GetClientContext({sp_url_here});
    var siteProps = new List();
    var tenant = new Tenant(context);
    string nextStartIndex = null;
    var sspFilter = new SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter
    {
        IncludePersonalSite = PersonalSiteFilter.Exclude,
        IncludeDetail = true,
        StartIndex = nextStartIndex,
    };    
    do
    {
        sspFilter.StartIndex = nextStartIndex;
        var chunk = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters(sspFilter);
        context.Load(chunk);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    
        siteProps.AddRange(chunk);
    
        nextStartIndex = chunk.NextStartIndexFromSharePoint;
    }
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextStartIndex));
```